# Import/Index a JSON file into Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and have been entering data manually up until this point. For example I've done something like this:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}'
```

I now have a .json file and I want to index this into Elasticsearch.  I've tried something like this too, but no success:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://jfblouvmlxecs01:9200/test/test/1' -d lane.json
```

How do I import a .json file?  Are there steps I need to take first to ensure the mapping is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any way to import a json file(contains 100 documents) in elasticsearch server.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646836/is-there-any-way-to-import-a-json-filecontains-100-documents-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The right command if you want to use a file with curl is this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://jfblouvmlxecs01:9200/test/_doc/1' -d @lane.json
```

Elasticsearch is schemaless, therefore you don't necessarily need a mapping. If you send the json as it is and you use the default mapping, every field will be indexed and analyzed using the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer/).

If you want to interact with Elasticsearch through the command line, you may want to have a look at the [elasticshell](http://github.com/javanna/elasticshell) which should be a little bit handier than curl.

2019-07-10: Should be noted that custom [mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) is deprecated and should not be used. I updated the type in the url above to make it easier to see which was the index and which was the type as having both named "test" was confusing.

Comment: I does't work for me, when I type Your command the console does't provide any data.

Comment: @Konrad you replaced `jfblouvmlxecs01` with `localhost`, right?

Comment: What does the '@' before the file name used for?

Comment: clwen - the "@" tells curl to load the data from the json file.

Comment: hi i am also new in elastic search can anyone please gudie me where to store these .json files?

Comment: You probably at least want to use scan/scroll you can lock the `snapshot` of your data as you export

Comment: Where to store json file?

Comment: Store it in your repo and @yogesh-darji when running curl, put it anywhere the system where curl running so it can read the file. It has to read it and send the contents to the URL. That is curl's job.

Comment: How to tell which name is after the port of elasticsearch? why do you put     `test/test1`?

Comment: @HomeMade First `test` is the index and second `test` is the type, finally followed by an `id` 1. See this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index_ .

Comment: hi, i get a respone in json format from a url now i want to store that json from remote url in to elasticsearch how can this be done? please help

Comment: @all I have analyzer in my json file now i want to execute that file how can i do that.

Comment: In my windows machine curl store at, system32 and it  don't allow to place my file there. So how can i setup full path where my file stored

Comment: When i execute this it gives body not found error, curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/document/_setting?pretty" -d @Elasticsearch_Spacial_Character_Analyzer.json

Answer (score 30):

Per the current docs, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html:

> If you’re providing text file input to curl, you must use the
>   --data-binary flag instead of plain -d. The latter doesn’t preserve newlines.

Example:

```
$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests
```

Comment: Note that the _bulk load json file is not valid a valid json file; the syntax is provided in the _bulk API link. Also, you do not have to provide an _id as indicated in these examples; an auto-generated _id will be provided when _id is omitted.

Answer (score 20):

One thing I've not seen anyone mention: the JSON file must have one line specifying the index the next line belongs to, for every line of the "pure" JSON file.

I.E.

```
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"act","_id":0}}
{"line_id":1,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"ACT I"}
```

Without that, nothing works, and it won't tell you why

Answer (score 19):

We made a little tool for this type of thing https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump

Comment: The given examples do not cover the question asked here. Will it work if we give the json file as an input and the elastic search url as the output?

Comment: I am using this to export the index into json. Thanks.

Comment: Use the following command. `elasticdump --input=/path/to/file.json --output=http://'username:password'@localhost:9200/indexname --type=data`.  Remove `'username:password@'` if you don't need.

Comment: This tool raises `not_x_content_exception` for plain line-delimited JSON and Bulk API JSON. It expects its own dump format, which looks like `{"_index":"my_index","_type":"_doc","_id":"abc","_score":1,"_source":{"my":"json"}}`.

Answer (score 13):

I'm the author of elasticsearch_loader
I wrote ESL for this exact problem.

You can download it with pip:

```
pip install elasticsearch-loader
```

And then you will be able to load json files into elasticsearch by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader --index incidents --type incident json file1.json file2.json
```

Comment: This is nice! It adds the mandatory `index` line before every document.

Comment: 2018-10-04 11:51:40.395741 ERROR attempt [1/1] got exception, it is a permanent data loss, no retry any more
2018-10-04 11:51:40.395741 WARN Chunk 0 got exception (ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10.0))) while processing

Comment: Apart from the fact that it doesn't work, where do you specify the URL and port?

Comment: You can visit the GitHub page or run `elasticsearch_loader --help` in order to view the full help message.
You can specify the host:port with `--es-host http://hostname:port`

Comment: Nice. Except that `--type` becomes redundant as Elasticsearch removes types in 6 version https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html

Comment: According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/removal-of-types.html Types will be deprecated in APIs in Elasticsearch 7.0.0, and completely removed in 8.0.0. I've added _doc as a default type, I will add tests for version 7

Answer (score 10):

I just made sure that I am in the same directory as the json file and then simply ran this

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/product/default/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @product.json
```

So if you too make sure you are at the same directory and run it this way.
Note: product/default/ in the command is something specific to my environment. you can omit it or replace it with whatever is relevant to you.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to KenH's answer

```
$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests
```

You can replace `@requests` with `@complete_path_to_json_file`

Note: `@`is important before the file path

Comment: can u give some example for path.
i am giving "@c:\accounts.json" and placing it there even then, its not able to locate it

Comment: it should be @"c:\accounts.json"

Comment: add a header flag like so  -H  "Content-Type: application/json"

Answer (score 6):

just get postman from https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments give it the file location with /test/test/1/_bulk?pretty command.
[image]

Comment: {
    "error": "no handler found for uri [/test/test/1/_bulk?pretty] and method [POST]"
}

Comment: {
    "error": "Content-Type header [text/plain] is not supported",
    "status": 406
}

Answer (score 6):

You are using

```
$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests
```

If 'requests' is a json file then you have to change this to

```
$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests.json
```

Now before this, if your json file is not indexed, you have to insert an index line before each line inside the json file. You can do this with JQ. Refer below link:
http://kevinmarsh.com/2014/10/23/using-jq-to-import-json-into-elasticsearch.html

Go to elasticsearch tutorials (example the shakespeare tutorial) and download the json file sample used and have a look at it. In front of each json object (each individual line) there is an index line. This is what you are looking for after using the jq command. This format is mandatory to use the bulk API, plain json files wont work.

Answer (score 3):

As of Elasticsearch 7.7, you have to specify the content type also:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @<absolute path to JSON file>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some code to expose the Elasticsearch API via a Filesystem API.

It is good idea for clear export/import of data for example.

I created **prototype** [elasticdriver](https://github.com/YaroslavGaponov/elasticdriver).  It is based on [FUSE](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

- If you are using the elastic search 7.7 or above version then follow below command.

  `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:9200/bank/_bulk? pretty&refresh" --data-binary @"/Users/waseem.khan/waseem/elastic/account.json"`
- On above file path is `/Users/waseem.khan/waseem/elastic/account.json`.
- If you are using elastic search 6.x version then you can use the below command.

`curl -X POST localhost:9200/bank/_bulk?pretty&refresh --data-binary @"/Users/waseem.khan/waseem/elastic/account.json" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

**Note**: Make sure in your **.json** file at the end you will add the one empty
line otherwise you will be getting below exception.

```
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
  }
],
"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
},
`enter code here`"status" : 400
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using VirtualBox and UBUNTU in it or you are simply using UBUNTU then it can be useful

```
wget https://github.com/andrewvc/ee-datasets/archive/master.zip
sudo apt-get install unzip (only if unzip module is not installed)
unzip master.zip
cd ee-datasets
java -jar elastic-loader.jar http://localhost:9200 datasets/movie_db.eloader
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to import a json file into Elasticsearch and create an index, use this Python script.

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
i = 0
with open('el_dharan.json') as raw_data:
    json_docs = json.load(raw_data)
    for json_doc in json_docs:
            i = i + 1
            es.index(index='ind_dharan', doc_type='doc_dharan', id=i, body=json.dumps(json_doc))
```

Comment: highly not recommended with large number of documents. as it does one single insert request per document, this one is incredibly unperformant.