# Insert multiple documents in Elasticsearch - bulk doc formatter

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

TLDR; How can I bulk format my JSON file for ingestion to Elasticsearch?

I am attempting to ingest some NOAA data into Elasticsearch and have been utilizing  [NOAA Python SDK](https://github.com/paulokuong/noaa).

I have written the following Python script to load the data and store it in a JSON format.

```
from noaa_sdk import noaa
import json

n = noaa.NOAA()
alerts = n.alerts()
f = open('nhc_alerts.json', 'w')
json.dump(alerts, f)
f.write('\n')
```

JSON Output:

```
{"@context": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojson/geojson-ld/master/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld", {"wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#", "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"}], "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-5246", "type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-5246", "@type": "wx:Alert", "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-5246", "areaDesc": "Montgomery", "geocode": {"UGC": ["MDC031"], "SAME": ["024031"]}, "affectedZones": ["https://api.weather.gov/zones/county/MDC031"], "references": [], "sent": "2020-04-25T19:21:03+00:00", "effective": "2020-04-25T19:21:03+00:00", "onset": null, "expires": "2020-04-25T19:31:03+00:00", "ends": null, "status": "Test", "messageType": "Alert", "category": "Met", "severity": "Unknown", "certainty": "Unknown", "urgency": "Unknown", "event": "Test Message", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "senderName": "NWS", "headline": null, "description": "Monitoring message only. Please disregard.", "instruction": "Monitoring message only. Please disregard.", "response": "None", "parameters": {"PIL": ["NWSKEPWBC"], "BLOCKCHANNEL": ["CMAS", "EAS", "NWEM"]}}}, {"id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4179499-3536427", "type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4179499-3536427", "@type": "wx:Alert", "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4179499-3536427", "areaDesc": "La Salle; Livingston", "geocode": {"UGC": ["ILZ019", "ILZ032"], "SAME": ["017099", "017105"]}, "affectedZones": ["https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ILZ019", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ILZ032"], "references": [{"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4179245-3536278", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4179245-3536278", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-04-25T10:02:00-05:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4178935-3536074", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4178935-3536074", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-04-25T03:09:00-05:00"}], "sent": "2020-04-25T14:21:00-05:00", "effective": "2020-04-25T14:21:00-05:00", "onset": "2020-04-25T14:21:00-05:00", "expires": "2020-04-25T22:30:00-05:00", "ends": "2020-04-26T01:00:00-05:00", "status": "Actual", "messageType": "Update", "category": "Met", "severity": "Severe", "certainty": "Possible", "urgency": "Future", "event": "Flood Watch", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "senderName": "NWS Chicago IL", "headline": "Flood Watch issued April 25 at 2:21PM CDT until April 26 at 1:00AM CDT by NWS Chicago IL", "description": "The Flood Watch is now in effect for\n\n* Livingston and La Salle counties in north central Illinois\n\n* Until 1 AM CDT Sunday\n\n* WHAT...Steady rain. One to two inches of rain has already\nfallen. Additional rainfall amounts of one inch or locally more\nare possible which may lead to total rainfall amounts in excess\nof three inches.\n\n* IMPACTS...Rises in rivers and small streams will occur with\nflooding possible. This especially includes the Vermilion River\nand its tributary streams, and the Illinois River. Roadways,\nviaducts, ditches, agricultural land, and other poor drainage\nareas may become flooded.", "instruction": "A Flood Watch means there is a potential for flooding based on\ncurrent forecasts.\n\nYou should monitor later forecasts and be alert for possible\nFlood Warnings. Those living in areas prone to flooding should be\nprepared to take action should flooding develop.", "response": "Prepare", "parameters": {"NWSheadline": ["FLOOD WATCH NOW IN EFFECT UNTIL 1 AM CDT SUNDAY"], "VTEC": ["/O.EXT.KLOT.FA.A.0002.000000T0000Z-200426T0600Z/"], "EAS-ORG": ["WXR"], "PIL": ["LOTFFALOT"], "BLOCKCHANNEL": ["CMAS", "EAS", "NWEM"], "eventEndingTime": ["2020-04-26T01:00:00-05:00"]}}}, {"id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4179497-3536425", "type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4179497-3536425", "@type": "wx:Alert", "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4179497-3536425", "areaDesc": "San Luis Obispo County Central Coast; Santa Barbara County Central Coast; Santa Ynez Valley", "geocode": {"UGC": ["CAZ034", "CAZ035", "CAZ036"], "SAME": ["006079", "006083"]}, "affectedZones": ["https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/CAZ034", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/CAZ035", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/CAZ036"], "references": [{"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4177692-3535278", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4177692-3535278", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-04-24T08:54:00-07:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4178774-3535999", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4178774-3535999", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-04-24T21:37:00-07:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4179040-3536147", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4179040-3536147", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent":
```

This script takes care of some of the formatting issues I encountered, my next hurdle has been attempting to format it so that I can utilize the bulk import function in elasticsearch. I stumbled across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33981143) which works to an extent, the issue that I run into is that it will insert the appropriate Index string, but it is doing it after every character.

The bulk convert script:

```
import json


JSON_FILE_IN = "nhc_alerts.json"
JSON_FILE_OUT = "nhc_bulk.json"


out = open(JSON_FILE_OUT, 'w')
with open(JSON_FILE_IN, 'r') as json_in:
    docs = json.dumps(json_in.read())
    for doc in docs:
        out.write('%s\n' % json.dumps({'index': {}}));
        out.write('%s\n' % json.dumps(doc, indent=0).replace('\n', ''))
```

Output from bulk script:

```
{"index": {}}
"\""
{"index": {}}
"{"
{"index": {}}
"\\"
{"index": {}}
"\""
{"index": {}}
"@"
{"index": {}}
"c"
{"index": {}}
"o"
{"index": {}}
"n"
{"index": {}}
"t"
{"index": {}}
"e"
{"index": {}}
"x"
{"index": {}}
"t"
{"index": {}}
"\\"
{"index": {}}
"\""
{"index": {}}
":"
{"index": {}}
" "
{"index": {}}
"["
{"index": {}}
"\\"
{"index": {}}
"\""
{"index": {}}
"h"
{"index": {}}
"t"
{"index": {}}
"t"
{"index": {}}
"p"
{"index": {}}
"s"
{"index": {}}
":"
{"index": {}}
"/"
{"index": {}}
"/"
{"index": {}}
"r"
{"index": {}}
"a"
{"index": {}}
"w"
{"index": {}}
"."
{"index": {}}
"g"
{"index": {}}
"i"
{"index": {}}
"t"
{"index": {}}
"h"
{"index": {}}
"u"
{"index": {}}
"b"
{"index": {}}
"u"
{"index": {}}
"s"
{"index": {}}
"e"
{"index": {}}
"r"
{"index": {}}
"c"
{"index": {}}
"o"
{"index": {}}
"n"
{"index": {}}
```

Ideally, I'd like to combine both of these scripts into one, but at this point, I'll run two separate scripts if it gets the job done.

Comment: What was your question again exactly?

Comment: Do you want to index the contents of `alerts['features']`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 How can I bulk format my JSON file for ingestion to Elasticsearch?

Comment: Can you share the first few lines of `nhc_alerts.json`? I suspect there are no newlines in it (and thus you're iterating over characters of a long line) and that you need to iterate over `alerts` instead of dumping them all in one shot

Comment: @val added an excerpt from nhc_alerts.json

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought... it's all on a single line, so it's not gonna work as it is. Do you want to index the elements present in the `alert.features` array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could utilize the `bulk` method of the official python package:

```
import json

from noaa_sdk import noaa
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk


noaa_client = noaa.NOAA()
alerts = noaa_client.alerts()['features']

es = Elasticsearch()


def save_alerts():
    with open('nhc_alerts.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(alerts))


def bulk_sync():
    actions = [
        {
            "_index": "my_noaa_index",
            "_source": alert
        } for alert in alerts
    ]

    bulk(es, actions)


save_alerts()
bulk_sync()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `alerts` JSON dump is all on a single line, so it's not gonna work as it is. You need to iterate on all the alerts (I suspect whatever is in the `alerts.features` array) and do it all in one shot without going through an intermediary file, like this:

```
n = noaa.NOAA()
alerts = n.alerts()
f = open('nhc_alerts.json', 'w')
for alert in alerts['features']:
  f.write('%s\n' % json.dumps({'index': {}}));
  f.write('%s\n' % json.dumps(alert, indent=0).replace('\n', ''))
f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this line to result in an error later on `json.dumps(json_in.read())`. `json.dumps` returns a string. When you iterate over a string, like you do in the next line, then you iterate over the chars.

I think what you actually want is the following. It saves every `feature` of `alert["features“]` as a new line in json format.

```py
from noaa_sdk import noaa
import json
from pathlib import Path


noaa_client = noaa.NOAA()
alerts = noaa_client.alerts()

save_path = Path('.') / "alert.json"
with save_path.open("a") as f:
    for feature in alerts["features"]:
        json.dump(feature, f)
        f.write("\n")
```

Result:

```
{"id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-16211", "type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-16211", "@type": "wx:Alert", "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-16211", "areaDesc": "Montgomery", "geocode": {"UGC": ["MDC031"], "SAME": ["024031"]}, "affectedZones": ["https://api.weather.gov/zones/county/MDC031"], "references": [], "sent": "2020-05-06T16:55:56+00:00", "effective": "2020-05-06T16:55:56+00:00", "onset": null, "expires": "2020-05-06T17:05:56+00:00", "ends": null, "status": "Test", "messageType": "Alert", "category": "Met", "severity": "Unknown", "certainty": "Unknown", "urgency": "Unknown", "event": "Test Message", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "senderName": "NWS", "headline": null, "description": "Monitoring message only. Please disregard.", "instruction": "Monitoring message only. Please disregard.", "response": "None", "parameters": {"PIL": ["NWSKEPWBC"], "BLOCKCHANNEL": ["CMAS", "EAS", "NWEM"]}}}
{"id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197938-3548807", "type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197938-3548807", "@type": "wx:Alert", "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197938-3548807", "areaDesc": "Coastal waters from NC VA border to Currituck Beach Light NC out 20 nm; Coastal Waters from Cape Charles Light to Virginia-North Carolina border out to 20 nm", "geocode": {"UGC": ["ANZ658", "ANZ656"], "SAME": ["073658", "073656"]}, "affectedZones": ["https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ANZ658", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ANZ656"], "references": [{"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197751-3548667", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197751-3548667", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-05-06T09:51:00-04:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197640-3548624", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197640-3548624", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-05-06T06:35:00-04:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197422-3548452", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197422-3548452", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-05-06T03:25:00-04:00"}], "sent": "2020-05-06T12:54:00-04:00", "effective": "2020-05-06T12:54:00-04:00", "onset": "2020-05-07T04:00:00-04:00", "expires": "2020-05-06T21:00:00-04:00", "ends": "2020-05-07T13:00:00-04:00", "status": "Actual", "messageType": "Update", "category": "Met", "severity": "Minor", "certainty": "Likely", "urgency": "Expected", "event": "Small Craft Advisory", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "senderName": "NWS Wakefield VA", "headline": "Small Craft Advisory issued May 6 at 12:54PM EDT until May 7 at 1:00PM EDT by NWS Wakefield VA", "description": "* WHAT...Northwest winds 15 to 20 kt with gusts up to 25 kt and\nseas 3 to 5 ft expected.\n\n* WHERE...Coastal Waters from Cape Charles Light to Virginia-\nNorth Carolina border out to 20 nm and Coastal waters from NC\nVA border to Currituck Beach Light NC out 20 nm.\n\n* WHEN...From 4 AM to 1 PM EDT Thursday.\n\n* IMPACTS...Conditions will be hazardous to small craft.", "instruction": "Inexperienced mariners, especially those operating smaller\nvessels, should avoid navigating in hazardous conditions.", "response": "Avoid", "parameters": {"NWSheadline": ["SMALL CRAFT ADVISORY REMAINS IN EFFECT FROM 4 AM TO 1 PM EDT THURSDAY"], "VTEC": ["/O.CON.KAKQ.SC.Y.0054.200507T0800Z-200507T1700Z/"], "PIL": ["AKQMWWAKQ"], "BLOCKCHANNEL": ["CMAS", "EAS", "NWEM"], "eventEndingTime": ["2020-05-07T13:00:00-04:00"]}}}
{"id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197936-3548805", "type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197936-3548805", "@type": "wx:Alert", "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197936-3548805", "areaDesc": "Chesapeake Bay from Smith Point to Windmill Point VA; Chesapeake Bay from New Point Comfort to Little Creek VA; Chesapeake Bay from Windmill Point to New Point Comfort VA; Chesapeake Bay from Little Creek VA to Cape Henry VA including the Chesapeake Bay Bridge Tunnel", "geocode": {"UGC": ["ANZ630", "ANZ632", "ANZ631", "ANZ634"], "SAME": ["073630", "073632", "073631", "073634"]}, "affectedZones": ["https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ANZ630", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ANZ632", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ANZ631", "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/ANZ634"], "references": [{"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197423-3548453", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197423-3548453", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-05-06T03:25:00-04:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197750-3548666", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197750-3548666", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-05-06T09:51:00-04:00"}, {"@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-4197641-3548625", "identifier": "NWS-IDP-PROD-4197641-3548625", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "sent": "2020-05-06T06:35:00-04:00"}], "sent": "2020-05-06T12:54:00-04:00", "effective": "2020-05-06T12:54:00-04:00", "onset": "2020-05-06T22:00:00-04:00", "expires": "2020-05-06T21:00:00-04:00", "ends": "2020-05-07T13:00:00-04:00", "status": "Actual", "messageType": "Update", "category": "Met", "severity": "Minor", "certainty": "Likely", "urgency": "Expected", "event": "Small Craft Advisory", "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov", "senderName": "NWS Wakefield VA", "headline": "Small Craft Advisory issued May 6 at 12:54PM EDT until May 7 at 1:00PM EDT by NWS Wakefield VA", "description": "* WHAT...North winds 10 to 20 kt with gusts up to 25 kt and\nwaves 2 to 3 ft expected.\n\n* WHERE...Chesapeake Bay from Little Creek VA to Cape Henry VA\nincluding the Chesapeake Bay Bridge Tunnel, Chesapeake Bay\nfrom New Point Comfort to Little Creek VA, Chesapeake Bay from\nSmith Point to Windmill Point VA and Chesapeake Bay from\nWindmill Point to New Point Comfort VA.\n\n* WHEN...From 10 PM this evening to 1 PM EDT Thursday.\n\n* IMPACTS...Conditions will be hazardous to small craft.", "instruction": "Inexperienced mariners, especially those operating smaller\nvessels, should avoid navigating in hazardous conditions.", "response": "Avoid", "parameters": {"NWSheadline": ["SMALL CRAFT ADVISORY REMAINS IN EFFECT FROM 10 PM THIS EVENING TO 1 PM EDT THURSDAY"], "VTEC": ["/O.CON.KAKQ.SC.Y.0054.200507T0200Z-200507T1700Z/"], "PIL": ["AKQMWWAKQ"], "BLOCKCHANNEL": ["CMAS", "EAS", "NWEM"], "eventEndingTime": ["2020-05-07T13:00:00-04:00"]}}}
...
```