# Python-automated bulk request for Elasticsearch not working "must be terminated by a newline"

Tags: python, json, list, elasticsearch, python-requests

I am trying to automate a bulk request for Elasticsearch via Python.

Therefore, i am preparing the data for the request body as follows (saved in a list as separate rows):

data =
[{"index":{"_id": ID}},
{"tag": {"input": [tag], "weight":count}}]

Then i will use requests to do the Api call:

r = requests.put(endpoint, json = data, auth = auth)

This is giving me the Error:

b'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"},"status":400}'

I know that i need to put a newline at the end of the request, and there lies my problem:
How can i append a newline to that given data structure? I tried to append '\n' to my list at the end but that didnt work out.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Go a level lower and try to `curl` the endpoint from command line. See if this resolves your issues https://discuss.elastic.co/t/issue-with-json-bulk-insert-the-bulk-request-must-be-terminated-by-a-newline-n/165902/4 
When that works you can try to adjust your python code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I already made a bulk request from Postman to the same endpoint, which worked perfectly!

Comment: Ensure the API calls are exactly the same `put` vs `post`, headers, auth, data...

Comment: it is exactly the same. I also did some requests (Get and Post) to the endpoint which worked perfectly

Comment: Capture the API requests with Postman and you'll see they aren't exactly the same. If they were you wouldn't have an error with Python and no error without Python.

Comment: Thats right. The Problem is, that i am not able to get my json file into the right format (in this case ndjson with \n as the last line) in python, in Postman i am able to do that.
And thats where i am struggling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The payload's content type must be `ndjson` and the `index` attribute needs be specified as well. Here's a working snippet:

```py
import requests
import json

endpoint = 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk'


#                  vvvvvv
data = [{"index": {"_index": "123", "_id": 123}},
        {"tag": {"input": ['tag'], "weight":10}}]


#         vvv                                              vvv
payload = '\n'.join([json.dumps(line) for line in data]) + '\n'

r = requests.put(endpoint,
                 # `data` instead of `json`!
                 data=payload,
                 headers={           
                     # it's a requirement
                     'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson'
                 })

print(r.json())
```

P.S.: You may want to consider the [`bulk` helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642184/8160318) in the official py client.

Comment: That solution works perfectly thank you very much!
Although, i also tried it without including a name for the index attribute and it worked too. Are there any downsights in doing so?

Comment: No prob! It's required when you don't specify it in the `_bulk` path -- otherwise ES wouldn't know where to put the docs (no pun intended). I reckon it worked for you because you *did* specify it in your endpoint. More on this here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-api-request-body