# How to push the json to elastic search as json instead of PUT method

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How to push the data into elastic search from python code

Right now i m pushing data with `PUT` command

```
PUT /data/test/1
{
    "id": "Accounting 101",
    "dataproduct": "E3",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Thomas Baszo",
        "department": "finance",
        "facutly_type": "part-time",
        "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
        },
    "students_enrolled": 27,
    "course_publish_date": "2015-01-19",
    "course_description": "Act 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to accounting that teaches students how to read and compose basic financial statements"
}

PUT /data/test/2
{
    "name": "Accounting 101",
    "room": "E3",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Thomas Baszo",
        "department": "finance",
        "facutly_type": "part-time",
        "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
        },
    "students_enrolled": 27,
    "course_publish_date": "2015-01-19",
    "course_description": "Act 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to accounting that teaches students how to read and compose basic financial statements"
}
```

How to push with python

pseudo code

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.cluster.health()
es.indices.create(index='data', ignore=400)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either utilize the [`_bulk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642184/8160318) endpoint or simply `index` your docs one by one:

```
es.index('data',
         body={
             "name": "Accounting 101",
             "room": "E3"
             # ...
         },
         id=2)
```