# How to use bulk operator in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am using the elasticsearch client.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
   var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
   host:"https://********",
   log: 'trace',
});
```

I have JSON objects lets say

```
[{"name":"abc", "age": 23},{"name":"bcd", "age": 25}......]
```

My Goal to insert it in bulk. I tried but not working.

```
client.bulk({
    index: "person",
    type: '_doc',
    body: [{JSON}] // input as JSON format

})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs-ElasticSearch Bulk API error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728650/nodejs-elasticsearch-bulk-api-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Main thing that need to remember about bulk API, that:

> The actions are specified in the request body using a newline delimited JSON (NDJSON) structure.

So it is really important to follow request body formatting, with new lines, action and metadata.

Example:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/docs-bulk.html)