# StatusCodeError: [not_x_content_exception] Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Hello i new in elasticsearch and i tried to make search in Node.js with elastic search. I make JSON.stringify() show error. Internet said that problem with data format. If you working in elasticsearch in Node.JS. Can you help with code please? In search.js i try make function bulk, index that insert json data. I put JSON data from API if you need in parser code you can write but i think error in search.js.

My code (search.js):

```
const es = require('elasticsearch');
const search = async (search_keyword, data) => {
    const esClient = new es.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200',
        log: 'trace'
    });
    await esClient.indices.create({
        index: 'test',
        body: data,
    });
   await esClient.search({
        index: 'test',
        body: {
            query: {
                multi_match: {
                    query: search_keyword,
                    fields: ["id", "name", "snippet"],
                    operator: "or"
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
module.exports=search;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const parser = require('./parser/parser');
const search=require('./elasticsearch/search')
;(async () => {
    const  result  = await parser();
for (const item of result) {
    const data = JSON.parse(item.data);
    const output = data.items.map(({id, name, snippet}) => ({
        id,
        name,
        snippet
    }));
    //console.log(output);
    try {
        await search("JS", output);
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

})();
const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

Error:

```
StatusCodeError: [not_x_content_exception] Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
    at respond (D:\Programming\test-task\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:349:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (D:\Programming\test-task\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:306:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\test-task\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:173:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (D:\Programming\test-task\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4949:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  status: 500,
  displayName: 'InternalServerError',
  message: '[not_x_content_exception] Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes',
  path: '/test',
  query: {},
  body: {
    error: {
      root_cause: [Array],
      type: 'not_x_content_exception',
      reason: 'Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes'
    },
    status: 500
  },
  statusCode: 500,
  response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}],"type":"not_x_content_excep
tion","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"},"status":500}',
  toString: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problematic part is

```
await esClient.indices.create({
        index: 'test',
        body: data,
});
```

because `data` is the `output` you're passing to the search `search` function:

```
const output = data.items.map(({id, name, snippet}) => ({
        id,
        name,
        snippet
}));
```

which is guaranteed to be an array. And the `client.incides.create` function does not accept that. Check [this valid `.create` usage](https://gist.github.com/stekhn/6f02a18610bbb3905634729858a33795#file-prepareelastic-js-L34) and see if it helps you further.

---

P.S.: The search function does multiple things at once:

1. it instantiates the client
2. creates an index (with the hope of indexing docs -- which fails. Check out [`_bulk` indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37729612/8160318) instead.)
3. and performs the search.

All of this combined violates a principle called [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). See, the search function failed but it shouldn't have because there's nothing wrong with `search` per se. Even if it didn't fail, other people (or you in 6 months' time) reading the code will wonder why multiple unrelated actions are being performed there. So a bit of refactoring would be reasonable.