# Fill ElasticSearch index with documents from JSON using Spring

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How one can fill existing index in ES with multiple documents from JSON file using `spring` / `spring-data-elasticsearch` ?

EDIT

I am aware of ES BulkAPI and Spring's `elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(indexQueries);` 
method however that way I have to handle JSON parsing on my own ([I want to avoid this way](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#elasticsearchtemplate)). But in case when we already know the index and mapping I wonder if there is something more straightforward that would require only passing the `foo.json` file?

Comment: Fill means you want to index data in a JSON file. Right ?

Comment: I have a large JSON file that I want to put into ES that has corespondent index for the JSON data mapping.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646836/is-there-any-way-to-import-a-json-filecontains-100-documents-in-elasticsearch

Comment: I am aware of the BulkAPI if its what you had in mind. However, I am after the programmatic solution using spring.

Comment: You can use elasticsearchTemplate class(configured as bean) and then bulk index docs.

Comment: I have just mentioned it in my EDIT AND LINK. As I already have the index and mapping I would like to avoid manual creation of each end every document programmatically and then add it to `indexQueries`

Comment: I've added an answer. You may check

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a functionality like this in spring data elasticsearch. But you can do something like :-

1.Set proper mapping for index(with json structure)

2.Create index and put mapping.

3.Use JSON parser and parse input json file like this:-

```
     //parse json file
     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("mydoc\\test.js"));
     JSONObject jsonData = (JSONObject) object;
     // index parsed contents
     IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder().withIndexName(indexName).
                        withSource(jsonData.toString()).build();
     elasticsearchTemplate.index(indexQuery);
```

Am not sure if this is what you are looking at,but still this may help.