# Add a header line before each json document

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a json file with 1000 json object.
is there any way to add a header line before each json document ? Is there any easiest way ?

Example :     I have 1000 object like this

`{"id":58,"first_name":"Louis","last_name":"Jordan","email":"ljordan1l@nature.com","gender":"Male","Latitude":"-15.93444","Longitude":"-50.14028"}`

i want to add index header like below for every json object so that i can use in Elasticsearch Bulk api

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "unique_id" } }
{"id":58,"first_name":"Louis","last_name":"Jordan","email":"ljordan1l@nature.com","gender":"Male","Latitude":"-15.93444","Longitude":"-50.14028"}
```

Comment: Do you want to specify your own IDs, or are you willing to let ES generate them automatically for you?

Comment: No matter about IDs, auto generated or My Specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to leverage Logstash, you don't need to modify your file and can simply read it line by line and stream it to ES using the `elasticsearch` output which leverages the Bulk API.

Store the following Logstash configuration in a file named `es.conf` (make sure the file `path` and ES `hosts` match your settings):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/your/json"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_fields => ["@version", "@timestamp"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "test"
    document_type => "type1"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Then, you need to [install logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html) and you'll be able to run the following command in order to load your JSON files to your ES server:

```
bin/logstash -f es.conf
```

Comment: How can i run this snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to Add a header line before each json document.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899000/5029432

Comment: Cool, note, however, that one disadvantage of that solution is that it doesn't allow to specify a document ID.

Comment: @Val, when you import file by BULK API, id will be auto generate.

Comment: I know that, I was just mentioning this for those people stumbling upon this question with the need to specify their own id.