# how to load .json file in elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a .json file and I want to load into elastic search for filtering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import/Index a JSON file into Elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936616/import-index-a-json-file-into-elasticsearch)

Comment: This must help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213529/3357884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to get started is to use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). If you have a JSON file with a *single* document, you could index it like this:

```
$ curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/default" -d@file.json
```

`example` is the index name and `default` the doc [type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html#glossary-type).

For more information, take a look at the docs:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html