# Elasticsearch Bulk Index JSON Data

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to bulk index a JSON file into a new Elasticsearch index and am unable to do so. I have the following sample data inside the JSON

```
[{"Amount": "480", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2105", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2107", "Quantity": "3", "Id": "974920111", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2115", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463798", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2116", "Quantity": "1", "Id": "975463827", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "648", "Quantity": "3", "Id": "975464139", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2126", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975464805", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2133", "Quantity": "1", "Id": "975464061", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "1339", "Quantity": "4", "Id": "974919458", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "1196", "Quantity": "5", "Id": "974920538", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "1198", "Quantity": "4", "Id": "975463638", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "1345", "Quantity": "4", "Id": "974919522", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "1347", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "974919563", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "673", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975464359", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "2153", "Quantity": "1", "Id": "975464511", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "3896", "Quantity": "4", "Id": "977289342", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"Amount": "3897", "Quantity": "4", "Id": "974920602", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}]
```

I am using

```
 curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_local/my_doc_type/_bulk --data-binary --data @/home/data1.json
```

When I try to use the standard bulk index API from Elasticsearch I get this error

```
 error: {"message":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]"}
```

Can anyone help with indexing this type of JSON?

Comment: can you tell me the index request you are using

Comment: @KumarKailash here is request curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_local/my_doc_type/_bulk --data-binary --data  @/home/data1.json

Comment: Try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213529/3357884

Answer (score 109, accepted):

What you need to do is to read that JSON file and then build a bulk request with the format expected by the [`_bulk` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), i.e. one line for the command and one line for the document, separated by a newline character... rinse and repeat for each document:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_bulk -d '
{"index": {"_index": "your_index", "_type": "your_type", "_id": "975463711"}}
{"Amount": "480", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
{"index": {"_index": "your_index", "_type": "your_type", "_id": "975463943"}}
{"Amount": "2105", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
... etc for all your documents
'
```

Just make sure to replace `your_index` and `your_type` with the actual index and type names you're using.

**UPDATE**

Note that the command-line can be shortened, by removing `_index` and `_type` if those are specified in your URL. It is also possible to remove `_id` if you specify the [path to your id field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) in your mapping (note that this feature will be deprecated in ES 2.0, though). At the very least, your command line can look like `{"index":{}}` for all documents but it will always be mandatory in order to specify which kind of operation you want to perform (in this case `index` the document)

**UPDATE 2**

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_local/my_doc_type/_bulk --data-binary  @/home/data1.json
```

`/home/data1.json` should look like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "480", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "2105", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "2107", "Quantity": "3", "Id": "974920111", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
```

**UPDATE 3**

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604500/10878775) to see how to generate the new json style file mentioned in **UPDATE 2**.

**UPDATE 4**

As of ES 7.x, the `doc_type` is not necessary anymore and should simply be `_doc` instead of `my_doc_type`. As of ES 8.x, the doc type will be removed completely. You can read more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

Comment: I get the format that you have mentioned, but i wanted to ask if i can have a workaround so that I do not have to specify something like this                       {"index": {"_index": "your_index", "_type": "your_type", "_id": "975463711"}}     after each document in json ?

Comment: The command line is always mandatory for each document. If you add the index and type name in your URL (i.e. `localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_bulk`), you can remove `_index` and `_type` from the command line to shorten it. There's also a way to not have to specify `_id` but at the very least, you'll always need to specify what operation you want to perform with the document, i.e. the shortest you can do is `{"index":{}}`

Comment: So the request curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_local/my_doc_type/_bulk --data-binary --data @/home/data1.json       where i have specified the index and the doc_type in the request , my json data should look like this?           [{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "480", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "2105", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"},
{"index":{}}
{"Amount": "2107", "Quantity": "3", "Id": "974920111", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
]

Comment: You don't need to specify your JSON objects inside an array (i.e. `[...]`) and no commas between documents, just one JSON per line with newline characters at the end of each line (don't forget a newline after the last line). I've updated my answer with your latest code.

Comment: @Val Am i correct then in saying that you cannot simply pass in a .json object and that it needs to be parsed / transformed first (i.e. each item on it's own line and an added `index` header for each item? If so, is there a known tool that can be used to do this automatically? I ask cause I have a json file that contains 10 000 items, I assumed I would be able to pass the entire document in, however, I was quickly corrected.

Comment: @Hexie in your case, you can use UPDATE 2 above and a shell script one-liner to update your file and add the header line.

Comment: @Val Thanks for the quick response, but again that would mean manual manipulation right? Whereby I would need to update the json file to contain a new `header` row about each of the 10 000 entries? I can give you an example of my json data if you'd like but simply put would follow this: 
[  {  "fileName": "filename", "data":"massive string text data here" } ] x 10 000 (PS - i say 10 000 but this will have ten's of millions, i'm using thousands for a POC i'm busy with)

Comment: @Hexie I suggest you create a new question (possibly referencing this one) so other people might benefit from it.

Comment: @Val Fair suggestion - new question created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601344/elasticsearch-bulk-json-data

Comment: doc type seems to be deprecated now. POST Body of update 2 is unchanged but new url (which i find much more logic) is localhost:9200/index_local/_bulk

Comment: @Harry Good point, that answer was written a while ago. I've added another update. Thanks

Comment: Thats great! i just fear update 4 is not 100% correct as _doc is the doc_type and they want you now to completely toss it. E.g. when using /myindex/_doc/_bulk instead of /myindex/_bulk one gets a deprecation error in reply: #! Deprecation: [types removal] Specifying types in bulk requests is deprecated.

Comment: @Harry yes, but deprecation doesn't mean error, it's just not necessary to specify it, but not an error to do so. `_doc` is going to go away in ES 8 which is due in a few months from now. I've added some more context.

Comment: @Val can we add alias too in the index line?

Comment: @Scorpy only if the alias points to a single index underneath

Comment: Yes the bulk is for the same index but when I add alias to the index line command it says unknown parameter "_alias"

Comment: @Scorpy you need to call it `_index` not `_alias`

Comment: Oh no sorry i just thought the way we pass "_index" "_type" we could pass "_alias".

Answer (score 15):

As of today, 6.1.2 is the latest version of ElasticSearch, and the curl command that works for me on Windows (x64) is

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/my_index/my_index_type/_bulk -H "Content-Type: 
application/x-ndjson" --data-binary @D:\data\mydata.json
```

The format of the data that should be present in mydata.json remains the same as shown in @val's answer

Comment: A side note for `Content-Type` that we should not include `charset` in it as a bug will return HTTP 406 https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28123

Answer (score 3):

A valid **Elasticsearch bulk API** request would be something like (ending with a newline):

POST http://localhost:9200/products_slo_development_temp_2/productModel/_bulk

```
{ "index":{ } } 
{"RequestedCountry":"slo","Id":1860,"Title":"Stol"} 
{ "index":{ } } 
{"RequestedCountry":"slo","Id":1860,"Title":"Miza"}
```

Elasticsearch bulk api documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

**This is how I do it**

I send a POST http request with the `uri` valiable as the URI/URL of the http request and `elasticsearchJson` variable is the JSON sent in the body of the http request formatted for the Elasticsearch bulk api:

```
var uri = @"/" + indexName + "/productModel/_bulk";
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sqlResult);
var elasticsearchJson = GetElasticsearchBulkJsonFromJson(json, "RequestedCountry");
```

Helper method for generating the required json format for the Elasticsearch bulk api:

```
public string GetElasticsearchBulkJsonFromJson(string jsonStringWithArrayOfObjects, string firstParameterNameOfObjectInJsonStringArrayOfObjects)
{
  return @"{ ""index"":{ } } 
" + jsonStringWithArrayOfObjects.Substring(1, jsonStringWithArrayOfObjects.Length - 2).Replace(@",{""" + firstParameterNameOfObjectInJsonStringArrayOfObjects + @"""", @" 
{ ""index"":{ } } 
{""" + firstParameterNameOfObjectInJsonStringArrayOfObjects + @"""") + @"
";
}
```

The first property/field in my JSON object is the `RequestedCountry` property that's why I use it in this example.

`productModel` is my Elasticsearch document type.
`sqlResult` is a C# generic list with products.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for Elastic Search 7.x onwards. `_type` is deprecated. As others have mentioned, you can read the file programatically, and construct a request body as described below. Also, I see that each of your json object has the `Id` attribute. So, you could set the document's internal id (`_id`) to be the same as this attribute. Updated `_bulk` API would look like this:

HTTP Method: `POST`

URI: `/<index_name>/_bulk`

Request body (should end with a new line):

```
{"index":{"_id": "975463711"}}
{"Amount": "480", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
{"index":{"_id": "975463943"}}
{"Amount": "2105", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
```