# Insert header for each document before uploading to elastic search

Tags: json, windows, bash, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk

I have a ndjson file with the below format

```
{"field1": "data1" , "field2": "data2"}
{"field1": "data1" , "field2": "data2"}
....
```

I want to add a header like

```
{"index": {}}
```

before each document before using the bulk operation
   I found a similar question: [Elasticsearch Bulk JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601344/elasticsearch-bulk-json-data)

The solution is this jq command:

```
jq -cr ".[]" input.json | while read line; do echo '{"index":{}}'; echo $line; done > bulk.json
```

But I get this error:

```
'while' is not recognized as a internal or external command
```

What am I doing wrong? Im running Windows
Or is there a better solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `while` in your sample is a construct that is usually built-in a developer-friendly shell like e.g. sh, bash or zsh but windows doesn't provide out of the box. [See the bash docs for example](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html).

So if this is a one-time thing, probably the fastest solution is to just use some text editor and add the required action lines by using some multi-cursor functionality.

On the other hand, if you are restricted to Windows but want some kind of better shell to use this more often, you should have a look at the [cmder project](http://cmder.net/) that brings you a bash environment to your windows desktop when using the full version that is packaged with git-for-windows. This should allow you to use such scripting features even on a non linux or mac environment.