# Displaying two json lines

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jq, jsonlines

I want to produce a custom json line and display it together with another. I can only display one json line right now. I need to display the two sequentially. I'm adding property "index" to property "hits" with `curl data.json | jq '{"index": {"index": {}}} + .hits.hits[]'`

I've tried to pipe using `jq '.index + ._source'`, but that just concatenates the property to _source. I've tried `jq .index ._source`, but that's an error.

I can select either _source or .index by piping the result `jq ._source` or `jq .index`. That will produce json lines correctly. That's fine. Now I need the .index, before each json line of ._source.

I need the result to look like this:

```
{"index": {}}
{/* ._source json line*/}
{"index": {}}
{/* ._source json line*/}
and so on...
```

Thank you!

Comment: This answer which does exactly that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604500/4604579 but use `.hits.hits[]` instead of `.[]`

Comment: my bad @Val, missed that one

Comment: Please fix the question in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.  In particular, a valid JSON text that is representative of the input to jq would be helpful, along with the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score -1):

I got it. Using `jq '.index,._source'` did the trick.