# Attempting to use JQ to process json data : Elasticsearch bulk index api

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jq

This question arrises from the following post:

[Elasticsearch Bulk JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601344/elasticsearch-bulk-json-data)

`jq -c -r ".[]" C:\setting-es.json | while read line; do echo '{"index":{}}'; echo $line; done > bulk.json`

The above jq shell command is throwing error "Missing statement body in do loop"

I have tried to change syntax around but still it is not working. I am trying to write a shell script to transform the following data for elasticsearch's bulk api:

```
[{
    "codeId": "111",
    "association": [{
        "associationId": 123,
        "businessUnitsAssociationId": 1,
        "financialBusinessUnits": "DCS",
        "businessApprovalLimit": [{
            "businessApprovalLimitApprovalLimitId": 1,
            "itemMinAmount": "0.00",
            "itemMaxAmount": "0.00"
        }, {
            "businessApprovalLimitApprovalLimitId": 2,
            "itemMinAmount": "0.00",
            "itemMaxAmount": "0.00"
        }, {
            "businessApprovalLimitApprovalLimitId": 3,
            "itemMinAmount": "0.00",
            "itemMaxAmount": "0.00"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I am trying to transform it to the following:

```
{"index":{}}
[{"codeId":"111","association":[{"associationId":123,"businessUnitsAssociationId":1,"financialBusinessUnits":"DCS","businessApprovalLimit":[{"businessApprovalLimitApprovalLimitId":1,"itemMinAmount":"0.00","itemMaxAmount":"0.00",},{"businessApprovalLimitApprovalLimitId":2,"itemMinAmount":"0.00","itemMaxAmount":"0.00",},{"businessApprovalLimitApprovalLimitId":3,"itemMinAmount":"0.00","itemMaxAmount":"0.00",}]}]
```

Comment: values `True` and `False` spelled as invalid JSON values (in JSON those spelled lower case entirely) intentionally or mistakenly?

Comment: @Dmitry i have fixed it but regardless this is just dummy data

Comment: @Dmitry how does jtc know how each json data is brokern up? In my dummy data, I am having five data points, how does it know how each is being separated? I ask this because my **actual** dataset has nested values with each data point separated.. I can share if needed

Comment: in your example it's a stream of JSONs, i.e., you have listed 5 standalone JSONs (and `jtc` processes a stream of JSONs with the option `-a`). If your actual data are nested, then the query would be different (does not matter if it's a jq or `jtc`), please share the correct snippet of the input data then.

Comment: I have changed my data @Dmitry to reflect the nested structure.. basically i am having fields nested twice, such as itemMinAmount, and every json data point begins with { "codeId" : "some value" ..

Comment: The JSON sample is now invalid -- there are two extraneous commas.  Please fix.

Comment: @cluis92, in such case, the same `jtc` would work (but `-a` option could be removed, it's redundant as now it's a single JSON).

Comment: I am actually having around 1000 lines of the same styled json but am not able to share on SO as it would be too long

Comment: @cluis92, right, but it's not needed, showing a snippet which would suffice explaining the input concept and allowing building a correct solution is enough.

Comment: using your jtc command ```jtc: <bulk.json jtc -aT'[{"index":{ }}, {{}}]' | jtc -arw[:] ``` how am i specifying the input file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to the revised question, after correcting the invalid JSON (i.e., after removing two superfluous commas).

There is still no need for a shell loop.

At a bash or bash-like prompt:

```
jq -c '.[] | ({"index":{}}, [.])'  input.json
```

At a Powershell prompt, it might be easier to place the jq program into a file, and invoke jq with the `-f FILENAME` option.

Comment: there's more than superfluous commas in the sample json, there's missing curly and square brackets. I have fixed it, but it's pending a review.

Comment: @peak so would this jq command be run from a shell script, such as windows powershell? Here is what I tried ```jq -c '.[] | ({"index":{}}, [.])' jq -c '.[] | ({"index":{}}, [.])' @C:\Users\chris\dummy-json.json``` and it is saying 'Could not open file jq' in powershell

Comment: thank you @peak marked as accepted.. this was what worked for me `jq -c '.[] | ({"index":{}}, [.])' activity-es-jq.json > bulk-activity.json`

Answer (score 0):

[This response was based on the original question.]

There's no need for any shell loop:

```
$ jq -c '{"index":{}},.' input.json
{"index":{}}
{"str field":"some string","int field":12345,"bool field":true}
{"index":{}}
{"str field":"another string","int field":42,"bool field":false}
{"index":{}}
{"str field":"random string","int field":3856452,"bool field":true}
{"index":{}}
{"str field":"string value","int field":11111,"bool field":false}
{"index":{}}
{"str field":"last string","int field":54321,"bool field":true}
```

Comment: so the reason I am needing a loop is because my data is much larger than the above and it is not having {"index":{}} as headers between each data point (its technically not valid json, but this is the only way elasticsearch will accept the data..)