# How to insert a new line with content in front of each line in json?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, sed, iteration, jq

I think `sed` should be the command to do this, but I haven't figured out the proper command yet.

My json file looks like this :

```
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-06-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Trade/HTS_CA/1234abcd","DECISION":"AGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5","NAME":"something"}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-08-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Import/HTS_US/9876abcd","DECISION":"DISAGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5","NAME":"nicename"}
... more rows to follow
```

what I wanted to achieve is a json document with below contents:

```
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-06-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Trade/HTS_CA/1234abcd","DECISION":"AGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5","NAME":"something"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-08-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Import/HTS_US/9876abcd","DECISION":"DISAGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5","NAME":"nicename"}
... more rows to follow
```

so that I could run bulk load API against Elasticsearch.

The closest one is this one: [Elasticsearch Bulk JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601344/elasticsearch-bulk-json-data/45604500#45604500), but it split my json file into broken items instead of my desired format.

Any ideas how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `sed`:

```
     sed 's/^/{"index":{}}\
/'
```

The trick here is the `\`.

Alternatively, if your shell supports it:

```
sed $'s/^/{"index":{}}\n/'
```

or (as per @sundeep's suggestion):

```
sed $'i\\\n{"index":{}}\n'
```

#### Using jq:

```
jq -nc 'inputs | {"index":{}}, .'
```

Here, the key is the `-c` option to produce JSONLines.

#### Using awk:

```
awk '{print "{\"index\":{}}"; print;}'
```

Etc.

Comment: thanks but I didn't completely follow, say my input is this file: `data1.json`, my output is this name: `data2.json`, how will this command look like? thanks

Comment: Both sed and jq accept an input file as argument, so you could use the pattern: `COMMAND  data1.json > data2.json`

Comment: Could also use the `i` command instead of `s` command

Comment: perfect, this command worked: `jq -nc 'inputs | {"index":{}}, .' data2.json > data3.json` thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'i{"index":{}}' file
```

Insert `{"index":{}}` before each line.