# Add a new line in front of each line before writing to JSON format using Spark in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to add one new line in front of each of my json document before Spark writes it into my s3 bucket:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("ParquetTable")
val parkSQL = spark.sql("select LAST_MODIFIED_BY, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, NVL(CLASS_NAME, className) as CLASS_NAME, DECISION, TASK_TYPE_ID from ParquetTable")
parkSQL.show(false)
parkSQL.count()

parkSQL.write.json("s3://test-bucket/json-output-7/")
```

with only this command, it'll produce files with contents below:

```
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-06-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Trade/HTS_CA/1234abcd","DECISION":"AGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5"}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-08-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Import/HTS_US/9876abcd","DECISION":"DISAGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5"}
```

but, what I'd like to achieve is something like below:

```
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-06-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Trade/HTS_CA/1234abcd","DECISION":"AGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-08-26 12:02:03.0","CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Import/HTS_US/9876abcd","DECISION":"DISAGREE","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5"}
```

Any insight on how to achieve this result would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: any specific reason you want to add `{"index":{}}` ?

Comment: so that I could call `bulk` load API against Elasticsearch, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601344/elasticsearch-bulk-json-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code will concat `{"index":{}}` with existing row data in `DataFrame` & It will convert data into `json` then save json data using `text` format.

```
df
.select(
    lit("""{"index":{}}""").as("index"),
    to_json(struct($"*")).as("json_data")
)
.select(
    concat_ws(
        "\n", // This will split index column & other column data into two lines.
        $"index",
        $"json_data"
    ).as("data")
)
.write
.format("text") // This is required.
.save("s3://test-bucket/json-output-7/")
```

Final Output

```
cat part-00000-24619b28-6501-4763-b3de-1a2f72a5a4ec-c000.txt

{"index":{}}
{"CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Trade/HTS_CA/1234abcd","DECISION":"AGREE","LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-06-26 12:02:03.0","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5"}
{"index":{}}
{"CLASS_NAME":"/SC/Import/HTS_US/9876abcd","DECISION":"DISAGREE","LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-08-26 12:02:03.0","TASK_TYPE_ID":"abcd1234-832b-43b6-afa6-361253ffe1d5"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need them to be in `.json` format though.

Comment: oh.. I think it's not possible to use `json` format because if you use `json` format final output data will be `stringified`.

Comment: nvm, you are right, and using your command, I was able to bulk load this `.txt` file into my Elasticsearch, thanks a ton again!