# Unable to import json array file to elasticsearch index?

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch, import, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried to import json array file into elasticsearch using following commands,

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/unified/post/1' -d @unified.json
```

and

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/unified/post/_bulk' --data-binary @unified_1.json
```

But, it is throwing error message as

**{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x
_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}**

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you show file that you want to import?

Comment: The bulk api does not expect json input. This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340153/elasticsearch-bulk-index-json-data

Comment: The input file will be as follows : [{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":"value2"},....] . So, can you guide us.

Comment: You cannot use that input format. Check the [bulk api docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). You have to write some code to transform your file into the format the bulk api expects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with "@unified_1.json". It seems that the data inside is does not follow the appropriate json structure that is required.

Comment: json file consists of array of jsons inside it.

Comment: The json file should have the following structure.
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
action then document json.. not as json array.
please post a small part of the file to check it