# Upload new line JSON to Elasticsearch bulk API

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I'm trying to upload a new line JSON to Elasticsearch using the Bulk API. The bulk JSON I'm uploading looks like this, with each JSON on a new line:

```
{"ip": "x.x.x.x", "seen": true, "classification": "malicious", "spoofable": false, "first_seen": "2020-03-31", "last_seen": "2020-04-15", "actor": "unknown", "tags": ["ADB Worm", "HTTP Alt Scanner", "Mirai", "Web Scanner"], "cve": [], "metadata": {"country": "United Kingdom", "country_code": "GB", "city": "redacted", "organization": "redacted", "rdns": "", "asn": "ASxxx", "tor": false, "os": "Linux 2.2-3.x", "category": "isp"}, "raw_data": {"scan": [{"port": 80, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 81, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 88, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 5555, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 8080, "protocol": "TCP"}], "web": {}, "ja3": []}}
{"ip": "x.x.x.x", "seen": true, "classification": "malicious", "spoofable": true, "first_seen": "2020-04-09", "last_seen": "2020-04-11", "actor": "unknown", "tags": ["Eternalblue", "SMB Scanner"], "cve": ["CVE-2017-0144"], "metadata": {"country": "United Kingdom", "country_code": "GB", "city": "redacted", "organization": "redacted", "rdns": "host.somehost.com", "asn": "ASxxx", "tor": false, "os": "Windows 7/8", "category": "isp"}, "raw_data": {"scan": [{"port": 445, "protocol": "TCP"}], "web": {}, "ja3": []}}
{"ip": "x.x.x.x", "seen": true, "classification": "malicious", "spoofable": true, "first_seen": "2019-09-05", "last_seen": "2020-04-06", "actor": "unknown", "tags": ["Mirai"], "cve": [], "metadata": {"country": "United Kingdom", "country_code": "GB", "city": "redacted", "organization": "redacted", "rdns": "redacted", "asn": "ASxxx", "tor": false, "os": "Linux 2.2.x-3.x (Embedded)", "category": "isp"}, "raw_data": {"scan": [{"port": 23, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 2323, "protocol": "TCP"}], "web": {}, "ja3": []}}
```

There's no index or key at the head of the JSON. So of course when I try to upload it with this command (my_index is a blank index with no mapping).

```
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -X POST http://localhost:9200/my_index/_bulk --data-binary @my_newline_json.json
```

I get the error message:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"},"status":400}
```

So if I understand the problem correctly as per [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), the issue is that the error is because there's no index or type specified at the start of the JSON. My problem is that I don't understand how to add the necessary index and type so that the JSON can be read.

I'm using Curl to create and add data to my index so what would the best way be format a curl command to create the index properly and allow my JSON to be uploaded?

(I have previously used the excellent Elasticsearch_loader tool by [MosheZada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540123/moshezada) which lets you specify the index and type in the command. This worked well but I'm trying to understand what is happening in that command and how I could do the same thing with Curl if needed.)

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33340234/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index-name/doc-type/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @my_newline_json.json
```

Change your bulk JSON, to the following format. Your `my_newline_json.json` should look like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"ip": "x.x.x.x", "seen": true, "classification": "malicious", "spoofable": false, "first_seen": "2020-03-31", "last_seen": "2020-04-15", "actor": "unknown", "tags": ["ADB Worm", "HTTP Alt Scanner", "Mirai", "Web Scanner"], "cve": [], "metadata": {"country": "United Kingdom", "country_code": "GB", "city": "redacted", "organization": "redacted", "rdns": "", "asn": "ASxxx", "tor": false, "os": "Linux 2.2-3.x", "category": "isp"}, "raw_data": {"scan": [{"port": 80, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 81, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 88, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 5555, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 8080, "protocol": "TCP"}], "web": {}, "ja3": []}}
{"index":{}}
{"ip": "x.x.x.x", "seen": true, "classification": "malicious", "spoofable": true, "first_seen": "2020-04-09", "last_seen": "2020-04-11", "actor": "unknown", "tags": ["Eternalblue", "SMB Scanner"], "cve": ["CVE-2017-0144"], "metadata": {"country": "United Kingdom", "country_code": "GB", "city": "redacted", "organization": "redacted", "rdns": "host.somehost.com", "asn": "ASxxx", "tor": false, "os": "Windows 7/8", "category": "isp"}, "raw_data": {"scan": [{"port": 445, "protocol": "TCP"}], "web": {}, "ja3": []}}
{"index":{}}
{"ip": "x.x.x.x", "seen": true, "classification": "malicious", "spoofable": true, "first_seen": "2019-09-05", "last_seen": "2020-04-06", "actor": "unknown", "tags": ["Mirai"], "cve": [], "metadata": {"country": "United Kingdom", "country_code": "GB", "city": "redacted", "organization": "redacted", "rdns": "redacted", "asn": "ASxxx", "tor": false, "os": "Linux 2.2.x-3.x (Embedded)", "category": "isp"}, "raw_data": {"scan": [{"port": 23, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"port": 2323, "protocol": "TCP"}], "web": {}, "ja3": []}}
```

**Dont forget to add a new line at the end of your content.**

Format of bulk JSON:

[image]

Output Result:

[image]

Comment: @ipconfuse have you gone through my answer..is your issue resolved??

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. I managed to reformat my JSON as suggested and now it works perfectly thank you.

My account is new so you might not see my upvote but it's there.

Comment: @ipconfuse glad to know that it was helpful ;-)