# elastic search curl command error for bulk import json file "url not specified"

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, import, bulk

i am new to elastic search trying to bulk import accounts.json file with curl command. but every time got error URL not specified.
elasticsearch  and kibana folder are on desktop and also accounts.json file also on desktop.

here is the curl command with error

```
desktop user$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST'localhost:9200/bank/_bulk?pretty&refresh' --data-binary '@accounts.json'
```

curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this command to bulk import data:

```
 curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index-name/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @my_newline_json.json
```

**Make sure that you have correctly specified the path of your json file in the curl command**

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61249405/10348758), to know more about this.

Comment: sure. actually i am new to stack overflow, still learning.

Comment: @Coder-91 no worries :)