# Insert JSON file into Elasticsearch + Kibana

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch, kibana

I am currently working on an anomaly detection project based on elasticsearch and kibana. Recently I have converted csv file to json and tried to import this data to elasticsearch via Postman using Bulk API. Unfortunately all of the queries were wrong.

Then I have found this topic : [Import/Index a JSON file into Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936616/import-index-a-json-file-into-elasticsearch)

and tried following approach :

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/yahoodata/a4benchmark/4' --data-binary @Anomaly1.json
```

The answer I got :

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed
>   to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to
>   parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor
>   detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed
>   xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}

The data I am trying to insert has the following structure (Anomaly1.json):

```
[
  {
    "timestamps": 11,
    "value": 1,
    "anomaly": 1,
  },
  {
    "timestamps": 1112,
    "value": 211,
    "anomaly": 0,
  },
  {
    "timestamps": 2,
    "value": 1,
    "anomaly": 0,
  }
]
```

Comment: looks like its complaining that you dont specify the content type (you dont tell it that you're sending json), add  `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to the commandline and try again?

Comment: Do you want to store each anomaly in the array as a standalone document or is it a big document with all anomalies into a single array?

Comment: @Val

It is a single document with all anomalies in a single array. In the example that I gave in my first post, there are only two readings but in the actual document there is around 1000 of them.

Comment: @hanshenrik unfortunately it didn't help. I got the same error. I should put -H (...)  just before I specify the file (meaining before --data-binary )