# Importing json file to Kibana via UI

Tags: json, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I've just move from 5.2.1 to 5.2.2 (own bug fixed)
Before I migrated, I've export all queries/ searches to json file in order to upload it to the new Kibana version

At first, I've update the ES version and to make sure all works, I reopen Kibana 5.2.1 and import json file. All good :)

Afterward, updating to Kibana 5.2.2.
When I open it all searches, visualize and dashboard were in. Is this the proper and straightforward way to copy my data when updating version? 
Or maybe to use like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936616/import-index-a-json-file-into-elasticsearch)?

Tnx

Comment: Ok I got it and it's quite simple! when creating queries/ visualize in kibana, it saved it to .kibana default index pattern (in config file) in ES. So, when updating Kibana's version and reading from the same ES version, data will appear in the UI. In case user wish to save it to other index pattern, he should change it in config file. For more reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it and it's quite simple :)

when creating queries/ visualize in kibana, it saved it to .

kibana default index pattern (in config file) in ES. So, when updating Kibana's version and reading from the same ES version, data will appear in the UI.

In case user wish to save it to other index pattern, he should change it in config file.

For more reading see [here](http://elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html)