# How to import JSON file to ElasticSearch 6.x?

Tags: http, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I got a brand new empty installation of Elastic Search 6.1.1 running on port 9200 of my CentOS7 host. I have this "es.json" file with data sample ready to be inserted in the ES.

I also have a log file in which each line is a json chunk. I could use both to populate my ES database.

How do I insert this and other data to ES?

I didnt find good explanations on the documentation and on the internet. for some reason the docs does not make it very clear

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have to create an index for each of these data sets you have since indexes in ES 6 can only have a single mapping type now. Did you create an index?

Comment: Take a look at [Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) and [Bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) APIs. Also consider whether to define mappings or let ES generate [dynamic mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) for you. You could always use the [Reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) API if you need to change mappings in the future.

Comment: This helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213529/3357884

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `--data-binary` flag in `curl` to bulk import from a JSON file.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/{index}/{type}/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @es.json
```

Data can be posted to one of the endpoints - `/_bulk`, `/{index}/_bulk` or `{index}/{type}/_bulk`. When `{index}` or `{index}/{type}` is provided, they will be used by default on bulk items that don’t provide them explicitly.

`Content-Type: application/x-ndjson` stands for Newline delimited JSON.

Before importing the JSON file, you might want to [define mappings yourself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/mapping.html) or let Elasticsearch [generate mappings dynamically](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/dynamic-mapping.html) during import. If you don't want Elasticsearch to generate mappings dynamically during import, refer to [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/mapping.html) to define mappings yourself.

**References:**

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/docs-bulk.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/tutorial-load-dataset.html

Comment: URL is given in the answer (`localhost:9200/{index}/{type}/_bulk?pretty`). Replace `{index}` and `{type}` with the required values. Eg.: `localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_bulk?pretty`

Answer (score 1):

You can use elasticsearch_loader for loading json files into elasticsearch (2.X, 5.X, 6.X).

You can download it with pip:

```
pip install elasticsearch-loader
```

And then you will be able to load json files into elasticsearch by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader --index incidents --type incident json file1.json file2.json
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of elasticsearch_loader